# Compare two array of object to its value, unit test

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

Suppose I have two similar array, how can I write unittest to check if these array has the same values.  And these values are equal. I use mocha and enzyme for unit testing. What is the best way to compare this value?

```
const devices = [{
        deviceType: 'Tag',
        deviceId: 1,
        name: 'Tag For Sending and alarm',
        version: '',
        location: 'Room1',
        lastAliveMessage: '',
        deviceStatus: 'Active',
        actions: 'offline',

    },{
        deviceType: 'Tag1',
        deviceId: 2,
        name: 'Tag For Sending and alarm2 ',
        version: '',
        location: 'Room2',
        lastAliveMessage: '',
        deviceStatus: 'Active',
        actions: 'offline',
    }]

const devices2 = [{
        deviceType: 'Tag',
        deviceId: 1,
        name: 'Tag For Sending and alarm',
        version: '',
        location: 'Room1',
        lastAliveMessage: '',
        deviceStatus: 'Active',
        actions: 'offline',

    },{
        deviceType: 'Tag1',
        deviceId: 2,
        name: 'Tag For Sending and alarm2 ',
        version: '',
        location: 'Room2',
        lastAliveMessage: '',
        deviceStatus: 'Active',
        actions: 'offline',
    }]

 data.forEach(item => {
                devices.forEach(device =>{
item.deviceId.should.be.equal(device.deviceId))
                })
            })
```

Comment: I would use the `isEqual` function from the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual) library. Equality is a bit tricky in javascript, so if you don't feel like taking on that beast i would stick to [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual).

Comment: You can write your own function or you can use dozens of already existing assertion libraries that you can use with Mocha. Or you can use, as suggested in the previous comment, something like lodash that would help reduce the work needed to write custom code. What is best really varies from situation to situation, and the situation you describe in your question is not particularly distinctive. Any of the options I've mentioned are *a priori* good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Chai](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep) you can use `deep.equal` check if the arrays of the objects are the same. It will work even if the order of the keys in the object are not the same between the two.

```
expect(devices).to.deep.equal(devices2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
devices.forEach((device, index) => {  
     data[index].deviceType.props.children.should.be.equal(device.deviceType)
     data[index].deviceId.props.children.should.be.equal(device.deviceId)
        })
```

Comment: What if the order is different in both arrays, is the solution above will still work